# Jackson - Variable key

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm facing a little problem, I think some workaround can be find but I'm searching for the *proper* way to do it.

I use Selenium with Grid, and then I configure all my nodes with JSON files. Some browsers (Chrome, IE) needs specific drivers.

These drivers are defined by a key of that form: `webdriver.browser.driver` with browser = *chrome* or *ie*. So, we've got for example:

```
{"browserName": "chrome",
  "maxInstances": 5,
  "platform": "WINDOWS",
  "webdriver.chrome.driver": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" }

{"browserName": "internet explorer",
  "maxInstances": 1,
  "platform": "WINDOWS",
  "webdriver.ie.driver": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe" }
```

I want to get the value and put it in: `private String driverPath` of my POJO.

Is there a way to get the value of the key dynamically? Like a regex?

Comment: You should map the Json with a Pojo class

Comment: Already did it, and i said it.

Comment: Is that the content of 2 different json files?  If not, it's invalid json input.  If you can clarify the input, I can show you how to allocate storage and extract what you want using jackson (in java).

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually speaking, in both of your objects, the attributes `"webdriver.chrome.driver"` and `"webdriver.ie.driver"` represents the same entity: **the driver**, so the attribute should just be called driver.

Usually a `POJO <-> JSON` conversion is intended to be one to one, so one `Java` field per `JSON` field.

If you cannot change the `JSON` or you feel that you need them to be like they are right now, at least in `Jackson` and `GSON`, you can register a Custom Deserializer and manually make the parsing for that value.

You can see examples here: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization

Answer (score 0):

Parse it as a `List`, for example using jackson:

```
List<Map> list = (List<Map>) new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, List.class);
```

---

Here's some working code:

```
String json = "[{\"browserName\": \"chrome\",  \"maxInstances\": 5,\n  \"platform\": \"WINDOWS\",\n" +
        "  \"webdriver.chrome.driver\": \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe\" }," +
        "{\"browserName\": \"internet explorer\",  \"maxInstances\": 1," +
        "  \"platform\": \"WINDOWS\",  \"webdriver.ie.driver\": \"C:/Program Files (x86)/Internet Explorer/iexplore.exe\" }]";
List<Map> list = (List<Map>) new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, List.class);
String browser = "chrome";
String driver = list.stream()
    .<String>map(m -> (String) m.get("webdriver." + browser + ".driver"))
    .filter(s -> s != null)
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null); // C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe
```

`driver` will be `null` if not found